# Setting up K8S on AWS machine fails: api server not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I followed [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/setup-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-ec2-instance-ubuntu-using-kubeadm/) to set up K8S on an EC2 instance, and I can't get it to work. I am not using EKS, but instead I want to make my own installation of K8S by running three EC2 instances and make one the master and the two others the workers.

I installed Docker, which works fine:

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:46 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:00:51 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.7
  GitCommit:        0197261a30bf81f1ee8e6a4dd2dea0ef95d67ccb
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.3
  GitCommit:        v1.1.3-0-g6724737
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

And `kubectl`, `kubeadm` and `kubelet`.

I ran `kubeadm init` to initialize my cluster, but after doing so the cluster doesn't manage to start successfully. It is possible to run `kubectl cluster-info` for a while, but after some time `kubelet` seems to just give up and commands answer with `The connection to the server 172.31.10.55:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`.

When looking at the output of `kubectl describe pod kube-apiserver-master -n=kube-system` I can see the following:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                  From     Message
  ----     ------          ----                 ----     -------
  Normal   Killing         30m                  kubelet  Stopping container kube-apiserver
  Normal   SandboxChanged  29m                  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          29m                  kubelet  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.24.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         29m                  kubelet  Created container kube-apiserver
  Normal   Started         29m                  kubelet  Started container kube-apiserver
  Warning  Unhealthy       29m                  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "https://172.31.10.55:6443/readyz": dial tcp 172.31.10.55:6443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy       29m                  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "https://172.31.10.55:6443/livez": dial tcp 172.31.10.55:6443: connect: connection refused
  Normal   SandboxChanged  29m                  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          29m                  kubelet  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.24.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         29m                  kubelet  Created container kube-apiserver
  Normal   Started         29m                  kubelet  Started container kube-apiserver
  Warning  Unhealthy       27m (x3 over 27m)    kubelet  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  Unhealthy       27m (x15 over 27m)   kubelet  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  Unhealthy       25m (x2 over 25m)    kubelet  Startup probe failed: Get "https://172.31.10.55:6443/livez": dial tcp 172.31.10.55:6443: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing         3m52s (x7 over 29m)  kubelet  Stopping container kube-apiserver
```

Looking at this, it seems that the issue is that K8S fails to access its own API on port `6443`, but the port is not restricted in AWS and anyway this should be internal requests, never coming out of the internal network.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious, but looking at other people with similar problems (6443 port reporting a connection refused) always seems unrelated to the issue I have here. I assume it's due to some network constraint in AWS but no idea which, since it's the first time I manage my own EC2 instances.

Comment: This is k8s the "hard way". If you need a single node test cluster, I recommend using kind: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/

Comment: I do not need a single node test cluster, but a three node cluster unfortunately. I'd like to figure out how to do it the hard way, since it is the way I need to ultimately go

Comment: To avoid the $35/mo charge for EKS?

Comment: [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) is probably your best best if you need to manually manage the master nodes of a cluster.

Comment: @jordanm because I'd rather not depend on AWS-specific tools in case I want to move the infrastructure elsewhere. I'll give kops a try, thanks!